# Java calender skipping first month

Tags: java, calendar

I am currently trying to make a Java program that simply prints out the dates for each day of the year. It work perfectly for every month in the year apart for January. Could anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong? Please find code below.

```
String date;

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 0);
        int maxDay = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int maxMon = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.MONTH);
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yy");
        for (int j = 0; j < maxMon; j++){
            for (int i = 0; i < maxDay; i++) {
                    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH , i);
                    date = df.format(cal.getTime());
                    System.out.println(date);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't see you set the month to `j` - intended?.

Comment: Exactly. The output is still wrong then, but includes January.

Comment: Please also specify what wrong output you get. Additionally keep in mind that maxDay would have to differ per month otherwise you might try to set the 30th of February etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you'd need to get `int maxDay = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);` inside the month loop.

Next, keep in mind that `MONTH` and `DAY_OF_MONTH` have different bases:
`MONTH` is 0-based and thus `maxMon` will be 11. `DAY_OF_MONTH` is 1-based and thus `maxDay` will be in the range 28-31.

So if you change your loops accordingly (start at `j = 0` and `i = 1` and use `j <= maxMon` and `i <= maxDay`) your results should be fine.

Comment: Thanks Thomas I really appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

Calendar's indexing is... special.

While `DAY_OF_MONTH` starts at 1, `MONTH` starts at zero. The `getActualMaximum` returns the actual maximum value, which also needs to be included in the loop. In addition to that, you didn't change the month field on your calendar instance while iterating over it.

I have taken the liberty to make your looping code more understandable.

```
String date;

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 0);

SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yy");
for (int i = 0; i <= cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.MONTH); i++) {
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, i);
    for (int j = 1; j <= cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); j++) {
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH , j);
        date = df.format(cal.getTime());
        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

The modern way is with the java.time classes. The old date-time classes are a mess, poorly-designed, confusing, and troublesome.

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

## `TemporalAdjuster`

The `TemporalAdjuster` interface provides for classes to manipulate date-time values. The `TemporalAdjusters` class (note the plural `s`) provides some handy implementations.

```
LocalDate firstOfMonth = today.with( TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth() );
```

Now loop through the month. Get the first of next month as our limit for the loop. Generating a string in an abbreviated format automatically localized to Québec.

```
LocalDate firstOfNextMonth = today.with( TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfNextMonth() );
LocalDate ld = firstOfMonth;
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( locale );
System.out.println( ld.getMonth().getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , locale ) );  // Print localized name of the month being reported.
do {
    System.out.println( ld.format( f ) );  // Create String representing this date.
} while ( ld.isBefore( firstOfNextMonth ) );
```

> octobre
>
> 16-10-01
>
> 16-10-02
>
> …

See [code in action](http://ideone.com/pPWwDZ).